# Рандом случайных чисел

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer, qspinbox

Я хочу сделать так, что когда я ввожу в первый `lineedit` например **`1`** и во второй **`17`** то рандом должен генерировать число в этом диапазоне и выводить его в `spinbox`.

```
import sys
import lo12
from random import randint
from random import randrange
from lo12 import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class PopolnenieApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):          # +  Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.myMinimize)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myClose)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) 
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.random)


    

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.setGeometry(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).x(),
                                self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).y(),
                                self.width(),
                                self.height())
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False



    def myClose(self):
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.close()


    def myMinimize(self):
#        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.showMinimized()  

    def random(self, value):
        A =QlineEdit_3
        B =QlineEdit_4
        el = randint(1, 9)
        self.spinBox.setValue(int(el))
        
        


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PopolnenieApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()







class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(374, 500)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(92, 37, 141, 255), stop:1 rgba(67, 137, 162, 255));\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 190, 81, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.lineEdit_3.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10px;\n"
"color: rgb(82, 66, 163);\n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(220, 63, 1, 255), stop:1 rgba(231, 234, 4, 255));")
        self.lineEdit_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 190, 81, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.lineEdit_4.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10px;\n"
"color: rgb(82, 66, 163);\n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(220, 63, 1, 255), stop:1 rgba(231, 234, 4, 255));")
        self.lineEdit_4.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-250, 0, 841, 41))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 571, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(149, 147, 173);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 0, 51, 41))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border:none;\n"
"background-color: transparent\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color:rgb(156, 52, 0)")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:\\random\\../Users/dimab/OneDrive/Desktop/close.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(31, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 0, 51, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("border:none;\n"
"background-color: transparent\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color:rgb(88, 201, 207)")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:\\random\\../Users/dimab/OneDrive/Desktop/lone.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_2.setIcon(icon1)
        self.pushButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(31, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 310, 201, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10px;\n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(220, 63, 1, 255), stop:1 rgba(231, 234, 4, 255));\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 70, 42, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setStyleSheet("border:none;\n"
"background-color: transparent")
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "От..."))
        self.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "До..."))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Random."))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сгенирировать"))
```

Comment: А зачем вам вообще A =QlineEdit_3 и B =QlineEdit_4 вы A и B нигде не используете всё-равно. Выкиньте эти строки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я отметил для вас строки, в которые внес изменения.

```
import sys
#import lo12
from random import randint
from random import randrange
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from lo12 import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(374, 500)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(92, 37, 141, 255), stop:1 rgba(67, 137, 162, 255));\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 190, 81, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.lineEdit_3.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10px;\n"
"color: rgb(82, 66, 163);\n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(220, 63, 1, 255), stop:1 rgba(231, 234, 4, 255));")
        self.lineEdit_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 190, 81, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.lineEdit_4.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10px;\n"
"color: rgb(82, 66, 163);\n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(220, 63, 1, 255), stop:1 rgba(231, 234, 4, 255));")
        self.lineEdit_4.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-250, 0, 841, 41))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 571, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(149, 147, 173);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 0, 51, 41))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border:none;\n"
"background-color: transparent\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color:rgb(156, 52, 0)")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:\\random\\../Users/dimab/OneDrive/Desktop/close.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(31, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 0, 51, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("border:none;\n"
"background-color: transparent\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color:rgb(88, 201, 207)")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:\\random\\../Users/dimab/OneDrive/Desktop/lone.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_2.setIcon(icon1)
        self.pushButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(31, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 310, 201, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10px;\n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(220, 63, 1, 255), stop:1 rgba(231, 234, 4, 255));\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 70, 142, 71))             # +++
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setStyleSheet("border:none;\n"
"background-color: transparent")
        self.spinBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "От..."))
        self.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "До..."))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Random."))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сгенирировать"))


class PopolnenieApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):          # +  Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.myMinimize)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myClose)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) 
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.random)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.setGeometry(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).x(),
                                self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).y(),
                                self.width(),
                                self.height())
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False

    def myClose(self):
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.close()

    def myMinimize(self):
#        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.showMinimized()  

    def random(self, value):
        a = int(self.lineEdit_3.text())       # QlineEdit_3
        b = int(self.lineEdit_4.text())       #  QlineEdit_4
        if a > b:
            return
        el = randint(a, b)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(b)            # ++++
        self.spinBox.setValue(int(el))


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PopolnenieApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]